# What is the name of this prime number algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, reference-request, primes

Does the following recursive algorithm have a name? If so, what is it?

```
procedure main():
 myFilter = new Filter( myPrime = 2 ) //first prime number
 print 2 //since it would not otherwise be printed
 for each n in 3 to MAX:
  if myFilter.isPrime(n):
   print n

object Filter:
 integer myPrime
 PrimeFilter nextFilter = NULL

 procedure isPrime(integer n):
  if n is multiple of myPrime:
   return FALSE
  else if nextFilter is not NULL:
   return nextFilter.isPrime(n)
  else
   nextFilter = new PrimeFilter(myPrime = n)
   return TRUE
```

[Sample implementation in Java here](http://pastebin.com/EFGpvkPT)

This is similar to the Sieve of Eratosthenes though after [some discussion in the CS chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/15610861#15610861), we decided that it is subtly different.

Comment: suggest a better question is `reference-request` to see where its been studied.... also its efficiency depends some on the implementation of the filter function...

Comment: I agree with Yuval Filmus, your algorithm doesnt seem efficient than the original. If you are trying to improve the algorithm, you might want to check this paper : [Two fast parallel prime number sieves](http://goo.gl/H9G03V) Their algorithm is much more efficient with the use of `wheel of factorization`. Although, it may not be theoretically work optimal but can be work optimal given specific computer architectures.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

O'Neil [1] call this the "unfaithful sieve". It's much slower than the sieve of Eratosthenes.

For each prime $p$ you do work $\sim p/\log p$ and so the total number of divisions up to $x$ is roughly $x^2/(2\log^2 x)$ if you assume composites are free. (That's essentially true: they take at most $2\sqrt x/\log x$ divisions each for a total of at most $2x^{3/2}/\log x$ divisions.)

Divisions take longer than unit time, so the total bit complexity is about $O(x^2\log\log x/\log x)$.

[1] Melissa E. O’Neill, [The Genuine Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://www.cs.hmc.edu/~oneill/papers/Sieve-JFP.pdf)

Comment: "Divisions take longer than unit time" -- depends on the model! What is the runtime of the Sieve in this model?

Comment: @Raphael: I use two models, one in which divisions have unit cost (giving $O(x^2/\log^2 x)$) and one with input/output tape Turing machines with fast arithmetic subroutines (FFT mult/div) which gives $O(x^2\log\log x/\log x)$. The latter makes my answer comparable to Filmus' second answer.

Answer (score 4):

Let me rephrase your algorithm (starting at a different base case):

```
Initialize P to be the empty list.
for n from 2 to MAX:
  if no integer in P divides n:
    add n to P
return P
```

Let $p_1,p_2,\ldots $ be an enumeration of the primes. The probability that $p_1,\ldots,p_i$ do not divide a number $n$ is roughly
$$ \prod_{j=1}^i \left(1 - \frac{1}{p_j}\right) \approx e^{-\sum_{j=1}^i p_j} \approx e^{-\sum_{j=1}^i j\log j} \approx e^{-\frac{1}{2} i^2 \log i}.$$
Therefore the inner loop runs for roughly this many iterations:
$$ \sum_{i=1}^\infty e^{-\frac{1}{2} i^2\log i} = O(1). $$
In total, the complexity is $O(n)$ divisions. In contrast, the Eratosthenes sieve requires $O(n\log\log n)$ additions.

For a fair comparison, we also need to factor it the computational complexity of operations on large numbers. Assuming that division can be done in time $O(m\log m)$ (which is the conjectured running time), where in our case $m = \log n$, your algorithm has bit complexity $O(n\log n\log\log n)$, matching the bit complexity of the sieve. However, the best known division algorithms are somewhat slower, both asymptotically and in practice, and so I expect your algorithm to be somewhat slower than the sieve.

[Atkin's sieve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Atkin) uses only $O(n/\log\log n)$ additions and so is faster than both your algorithm and the Eratosthenes sieve. It also uses only $\tilde{O}(\sqrt{n})$ memory, compared to your $\sum_{p_i \leq n} \log p_i \approx \sum_{m=1}^{n/\log n} \log(m\log m) = \Theta(n)$, also shared by the Eratosthenes sieve.

Comment: I get a very different analysis, see my answer.

Comment: @Sukotto: No problem. If I had remembered the reference sooner I could have just copied it, though. :)

Comment: Just in case someone wants to rush out and use the Sieve of Atkin, first read [GordonBGood's post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20572948/3126317) on the subject.  "is faster" should be read as "asymptotically faster if one ignores all actual implementation details."

Comment: @DanaJ: Agreed. I do expect that Atkin would win out eventually, but that would surely be for ranges $\gg10^{20}.$